# configure exim for system email forwarding (outside) , on a server with dynamic ip, behind a DNS router

Tags: debian, iptables, email, firewall, exim

Trying to configure exim to deleaver email to the outside world. I/We need to send email outside just for centralize certain admin notifications.

Working on an already configured debian webserver, it uses apache with proxy enabled, that use ajp connector to Tomcat7.

I've been thinking that the problems was related to iptables, but i was wrong, disabling it and testing didn't show any changes.

i really don't understand where the problem could be. with normal Virtual machines i can set up exim, or postfix, or simply mail, to deliver messages outside the local network, without problems. On that server i can't

Comment: Connections initiated by the client aren't usually blocked by iptables, but in instances where it is the firewall is just blocking the remote system's responses, not the client itself. So usually `iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT` fixes the issue.

Comment: That said, you might also think about whether there's a network-based firewall blocking the connection. Especially if you're doing a reverse proxy. Those setups are often behind a firewall that only lets the public clients connect on certain ports on the load balancer. If the internet server is trying to reply on some non-port 80 port number, the firewall would be catching it.

Comment: thank you so much for the really interesting comments, lot of skills behind them. i tryied to add the rule u mentioned, but still could not deleaver. later when i get home i ll analize your second comment to try to catch your hints :)

Answer (score 0):

```
# Allows SMTP access
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT

# Allows pop and pops connections
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT

# Allows imap and imaps connections 
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
```

replace smtp access with this line in iptables. comment out old line or change ouput as input.

Comment: i tryed to remove the 3 lines i added [see main question], and replycing them with your version. But mail deleavery still dows't work

Comment: found the way to stop iptables, but nothing changed

Comment: then problem not in iptables please check mail server configuration.